# Problemas ao excluir o primeiro elemento da lista encadeada

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Caros, para o exemplo, estou utilizando uma lista simplesmente encadeada, sem cabeça e preciso escrever uma função de excluir um elemento X na lista. Fiz o seguinte código:

```
#define Limite 21

typedef struct aluno{
    char nome[Limite];
    float nota;
    struct aluno* ponteiro;
}t_aluno;

aluno* cria_aluno(){
    aluno* novo = (aluno*)malloc(sizeof(aluno));
    return novo;
}

\\Insere no inicio
aluno* inserir_aluno(aluno* Lista, char nome[], float nota){
    aluno *novo_aluno = cria_aluno();
    
    strcpy(novo_aluno->nome, nome);
    novo_aluno->nota = nota;
    
    if(Lista == NULL){
        Lista = novo_aluno;
        novo_aluno->ponteiro = NULL;
    }else{
        novo_aluno->ponteiro = Lista;
        Lista = novo_aluno;
    }
    return Lista;
}

void excluir(aluno *Lista, aluno *anterior){    
        aluno* lixo;
        if(anterior != NULL){
            lixo = anterior->ponteiro;
        }else{
            lixo = Lista;
        }
    
        if(lixo == Lista && lixo->ponteiro == NULL){
            Lista = NULL;
        }else if(lixo == Lista && lixo->ponteiro != NULL){
            aluno *prox = lixo->ponteiro;
            printf("%s", prox->nome);
            Lista = lixo->ponteiro; 
        }else{
            anterior->ponteiro = lixo->ponteiro;
        }
        
        free(lixo);
}

aluno *indexPrev(aluno *Lista, char nome[]){
    if(Lista != NULL){
        aluno *i = Lista;
        aluno *prox = NULL;
        
        if(strcmp(nome, i->nome) == 0){
            i = NULL;
            return i;
        }
        
        while(i != NULL){
            prox = i->ponteiro;
            if (strcmp(nome, prox->nome) == 0){
                return i;
            }
            i = i->ponteiro;
        }
    }else{
        printf("Lista vazia \n");
    }
}

int main() {
        int total = 0;
        int v = 0;
        char nome_aluno[Limite];
        float nota = 0;
        t_aluno *Lista = NULL;
        
        while (v != 6){
        
        printf(" \n -------------------------------- \n ESCOLA \n -------------------------------- \n  1 - Cadastrar aluno \n  2 - Ver todos os alunos \n  3 - Ver relacao aprovados x reprovados \n  4 -  \n  5 - Excluir aluno \n 6 - Sair \n -------------------------------- \n");
        
        scanf("%d", &v);
        switch (v) {
        case 1:
            printf("  Insira o nome do aluno: ");
            scanf("%s", &nome_aluno);
            printf("  Insira a nota: ");
            scanf("%f", &nota);
            
            Lista = inserir_aluno(Lista, nome_aluno, nota);
           
            break;
        case 2:
            
            break;
        case 3:
            
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            char *n;
            
            printf("Informe o nome do aluno: \n");
            scanf("%s", nome_aluno);
            
            //aluno *index = indexOf(Lista, nome_aluno);
            aluno *anterior = indexPrev(Lista, nome_aluno);
            excluir(Lista, anterior);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

A função "excluir" exclui o elemento, caso ele esteja no meio ou no final da lista. Mas, quando está na primeira posição, o elemento não é excluído e ao *printar* a lista, ela me retorna um dado totalmente bagunçado, tal qual a imagem abaixo:
[image: problema no print]

Por gentileza, gostaria de saber onde estou errando e o que faz retornar este " *lixo* "?

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e poste o código de inserir elementos e o de criação da lista também. Seu exemplo deve ser reproduzível por qualquer um que queira te ajudar. Abraço!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rapaz, seu código tá bem bagunçadinho mas só pela descrição do problema já deu pra entender qual é o problema.

Existem 2 soluções possíveis:

1. Passar um ponteiro pra ponteiro como parâmetro pra tratar o caso específico de excluir o primeiro elemento.
2. Mudar o tipo de retorno de void pra aluno*.

A segunda sugestão é mais simples de entender... segue abaixo as alterações que mencionei.

```
  aluno* excluir(aluno *Lista, aluno *anterior){    // muda o cabeçalho aqui
    aluno* lixo;
    if(anterior != NULL){
        lixo = anterior->ponteiro;
    }else{
        lixo = Lista;
    }

    if(lixo == Lista && lixo->ponteiro == NULL){
        Lista = NULL;
    }else if(lixo == Lista && lixo->ponteiro != NULL){
        aluno *prox = lixo->ponteiro;
        printf("%s", prox->nome);
        Lista = lixo->ponteiro; 
    }else{
        anterior->ponteiro = lixo->ponteiro;
    }
    
    free(lixo);
    return Lista; //adiciona essa linha
```

}

e na hora de chamar...

```
Lista = excluir(Lista, anterior);
```

pra primeira opção seria algo do tipo:

```
 void excluir(aluno **Lista, aluno *anterior){    // alterou aqui
    aluno* lixo;
    if(anterior != NULL){
        lixo = anterior->ponteiro;
    }else{
        lixo = *Lista; //alterou aqui
    }

    if(lixo == *Lista && lixo->ponteiro == NULL){ //alterou aqui
        *Lista = NULL;
    }else if(lixo == *Lista && lixo->ponteiro != NULL){ //alterou aqui
        aluno *prox = lixo->ponteiro;
        printf("%s", prox->nome);
        *Lista = lixo->ponteiro; //alterou aqui
    }else{
        anterior->ponteiro = lixo->ponteiro;
    }
    
    free(lixo);
}
```

e depois chama com:

```
excluir(&Lista, anterior);
```

É dificil explicar só com texto... vou botar um exemplo aqui pra você ver a diferença.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void f1(int* pt)
{
   printf("endereco no inicio de f1 = %p\n", pt);
   pt = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
   printf("endereco no final de f1 = %p\n", pt);
}

void f2(int** pt)
{
   printf("endereco do parametro sem derreferenciar %p\n", pt);
   printf("endereco no inicio de f2 = %p\n", *pt);
   *pt = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
   printf("endereco no final de f2 = %p\n", *pt);
}

int main (){
   int *p = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)* 10);

   printf("O endereco incial de p eh: %p\n", p);
   f1(p);
   printf("O endereco de p depois de f1 eh: %p\n", p);
   f2(&p);
   printf("O endereco de p depois de f2 eh: %p\n", p);
}
```

Observe que o valor de p muda se chamar f2 mas não muda se chamar f1...

Comment: Já tinha feito retornando aluno*  o problema é que preciso, restritamente, fazer com o tipo void. Não consegui entender a primeira sugestão, poderia dar um exemplo ?

Comment: vou editar a resposta e adicionar no final

Comment: conseguiu entender?

Comment: Consegui sim ! Não tinha pensado dessa maneira antes e quando falou acima não tinha conseguido associar. Só tenho a agradecer pelo tempo que se dedicou para a solução!